# Use of [tag:econometrics] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I am curious about the use of the [econometrics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/econometrics) tag. Its Wiki says

> a field of statistics dealing with applications to economics.

This makes some sense, but I tend to think of the distinction between econometrics and the rest of statistics more in terms of *models and techniques* (such as structural models based on economic theory and instrumental variables estimation) rather than just the *applications*. Because on one hand one can do a "purely statistical" modelling of an applied economics problem, but on the other hand one can do something "typically econometric" (distinct from a typical statistical application).

I would rather have an `economics` tag for application in economics. Now we do have [macroeconomics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macroeconomics) and [finance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) tags for questions that have macroeconomics or finance as their applications. (Macroeconomics is clearly a subfield of economics, and finance can also be considered a subfield of economics, although this is less clear cut; so probably an `economics` tag would be too broad, I am not sure.) And that is just fine, it helps people interested in macroeconomic or financial applications track the relevant questions. Meanwhile, I would see a different role for the [econometrics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/econometrics) tag based on what I articulated above.

Any opinions?

Comment: That's not part of my expertise or interests and so I have no opinion, but I note that [econometrics] tag has 1k+ threads. That's a lot. Whatever you suggest should take this into account, e.g. even to look through all these threads is *a lot* of work, let alone doing some re-tagging. Also, it could help if you make a specific suggestion about what [econometrics] excerpt should say, and also a specific suggestion about what to do with the threads that would not fit this new description (and some estimate about how many of them there are).

Comment: @amoeba, When writing the question I did not think about doing any actual work in changing things in the existing threads (even though this is a very valid question); I though first about what to do with new question being tagged with [tag:econometrics]. Working on 1k+ existing threads certainly does sound complicated.

Comment: I find the econometrics tag very useful because it changes my interpretation of the intent of particular words (since econometricians tend to use some statistical terms - like *fixed effects* for example - in distinct ways), and it changes what approaches I might recommend (since the audience expects particular things and the common problems tend to be of particular kinds), for example. It may at least be worth considering whether the tag wiki could use an edit, though.

Comment: I have nothing against the tag itself, but it is often *used* to tag anything. I have a feeling that people often use it like "my econometrics book mentions regression, so regression = econometrics", "it mentions time-series as well, so time-series = econometrics" etc. literally everything becomes scope of econometrics.

Comment: @Glen, I agree that the tag is useful for interpretation, especially if the tag were used less broadly (which does not always happen -- see Tim's comment). For me attaching the tag to an applied economics problem that does not require specific econometric ways of thinking (models and techniques) does not help. **Tim**, I totally agree.

Comment: Richard and @Tim, why don't you try to suggest a more suitable tag excerpt?

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable to provide guidance in a tag wiki about how *not* to use a tag.